# Android - Is using static fields a good practice for surviving activity restart?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Recently I have found a way to survive configuration changes. What I do is I declare the objects I want to protect as static fields. Is this a good practice?

Comment: Can you enrich your question with some code describing your technique ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's never been a good practice. In my own experience I made a music player app with full of static variables and it's ram usage rocketed to more than 75 mb which is far more than any other of it's kind. The reason is, it stores the value of variable while activity is destroyed. if you have static variable on bitmaps or any other heavy file, it makes memory leaks which is not pleasant to see by user as not all devices got enough resources (ram) to keep up with heavy usage app.

Also static variables often make NullPointerExceptions as these are used by many other activities too and having a variable null may result in total failure of app...

I advise you to store the data in a SharedPreferences and just make one static field like integer and always use that to retrieve values from SharedPrefrences, its very clean and reduces the NullPointers. Moreover just one static makes u have more control over your app... For me it saves time to change 100's of static field rather than changing 1 as it's a lot easy and memory efficient...

I hope, I may help u a little !

Answer (score 2):

Not really. You can cause a memory leak, because one of your static fields can hold a reference to the current Context, which could be destroyed without the reference.

The best way to survive configuration changes is to use the recomended method - Bundles. If you have to store something bigger and/or more persistant - use files, SharedPreferences or a database.

Comment: I override on destroy and null the reference in the objects I want to protect then check in on create if they are not null if true I update the reference to the context that is if they hold a reference to the context at all...

Answer (score 1):

Use static may lead to nullpointer exception. Because when configuration change the current context is destroyed and if you access those context then it throws nullPointer exception.

So sharedPreferences or database is the best option for store the data.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach to retain Activity State, especially during configuration change is to make use of Fragments.

Instead of reinitializing your activity, you can alleviate the burden by retaining a Fragment when your activity is restarted due to a configuration change.

The fragments of your activity that you have marked to retain are not destroyed by Android system, when it destroyed your activity during configuration change.

You can add such fragments to your activity to preserve stateful objects.

Compare to using "static", this Approach is what being advocated at below link:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't just put in the bundle in onSaveInstanceState for some (very good) reason. So I think you have to compare with retain fragment.

If you have a static field in your class, like:

```
static Object myStaticReference;
```

you will no more worry about all the lifecycle jungle mess with onDestroy, onCreate, onSaveInstanceState of the Activity or Fragment. This will reduce considerably the code rows and make everything just easier to debug and understand. In any case you shall not have any reference in your object to a View, Activity, Fragment, Context and the like. 
If for example you have something like this:

```
public class MyObject {
    ArrayList metaData;
    Context cntx;
    public MyObject(Context cntx) {
         this.cntx=cntx;
    }
}
```

Then you still are in the lifecycle jungle, and you will have to pass (and repass) the reference of the context (and any other View relations you have) any time your Activity gets recreated in onCreate and still manage with onSaveInstanceState if there is any need. So in this case it is just useless.

With retain Fragment (which I suppose should be the other way) things are different too. The retain Fragment will last even when the Activity gets recreated, but you have to manage this additional fragment (the good part is that you do not need an UI for this).

Comment: It doesn't matter where you store your data to survive the configuration change, you cannot have a strong reference to a context, view etc... You will leak your context if you store it in the retained Fragment. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject